# How to stack two images on top of each other?

Tags: html, css

Image example of what I need

[image]

I basically copied the code off of a YouTube video. I am a rookie so try and explain as easily as possible how to stack two images on top of each other.
They are the same width and same height images and need to be aligned horizontally and vertically.

```css
.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -260px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="car.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML only has one image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this. The most simple would probably be to edit your CSS to do the following:

**CSS:**

```
.image {
    width: 100%; /* Image container is now full-width */
}

.image img {
    margin: 40px auto; /* "auto" will center block elements */
    display: block; /* Set images to be "block" so they obey our auto margin */
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image">
    <img src="path/to/image1.jpg">
    <img src="path/to/image2.jpg">
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Ldg3osr/7/)

---

**For horizontal *and* vertical centering:**

While some may prefer the `flex` method, I prefer the `table-cell` method for simple alignment. Try this:

**CSS:**

```
.image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px /* Modify this to fit your needs */
    display: table;
}

.image .centered {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.image .centered img {
    margin: 40px auto;
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="image">
    <div class="centered">
        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/360/100">
        <img src="http://fillmurray.com/360/100">
    </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8Ldg3osr/11/)

Comment: hank you Santi! One question though, they are not centered horizontally and vertically. They are centered horizontally though. http://imgur.com/a1vr3vd

Comment: @scwbrian I did not realize you wanted them centered vertically. This is only slightly more intricate. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Vertical and horizontal, yes. Sorry if I made you misunderstand something!

Comment: Thanks Santi, also I have a logo that's an image. How can I put it above the 2 images with also space for a menu?

Comment: Truthfully I'd suggest looking into it a bit further and learn it on your own! Not to shoot you down, but StackOverflow is a service to help fix errors with existing code. I helped you out by writing the alignment CSS for you, but I think moving forward you may be best looking at some basic HTML/CSS tutorials. Good luck, and if you found that my answer resolved your original issue, please mark it as *accepted* (by clicking the check-mark beside it). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the question is only to put second image under the first just br tag
If the question is to make on blank page 2 images in center one under one:

```
<table style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0px; margin: 0; border: 0;">
        <tr style="height: 100%">
            <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; height: 100%;">
                <img src="1.jpg" /><br><br>
                <img src="2.jpg" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

For body and html you need also height: 100%

I'm pretty sure all positioning is possible with div so probably I'm complicated with tables but I was too tired to find the code for vertical positioning so I used tables in my work.